# Unable to connect to web app written in PHP Codeigniter running on wamp in Windows Server 2008 through web browser of my local machine?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2

I have two web app (PHP Codeigniter) folders in wamp's www folder on my virtual machine Windows Server 2008. I am able to access and use one of the  web apps from my local machine through web browser without any problems. When I open the link for the second web app: 192.168.xx/second_webapp/, it gives the sign in page without an problem. However, when I log in, it switches the ip address of my virtual machine to "localhost" and therefore I get error unable to access the web app. Where should I look into to resolve this? Is it .htaccess configuration that I need to look into?

Comment: are you using relative urls? if they redirects and links contain localhost then that might be your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **./application/config/config.php** file, set:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.xx/second_webapp/';
```

You also need to set your .htaccess rewritebase:

```
RewriteBase /second_webapp
```

However, if you're using IIS you need to set a similar rule in your **Web.config** file. More info [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The issue, indeed, was in the **./application/config/config.php**  file.  However, I did not specify the base url. Instead I left it as blank **$config['base_url'] = ' ';** and now I am able to access this web app which is running on virtual machine through my local machine. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad to help!